# Copy and paste in the terminal?

Tags: command-line, copy-and-paste

How do you copy and paste inside the terminal?

I've tried with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>; neither works, they just insert `^C` or `^V` into the prompt. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: CTRL + SHIFT + C   and CTRL + SHIFT + V try this

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In order to copy and paste in the terminal, you need to include the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> key. For example:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = Copy
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> = Paste

Regular <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> won't work because the terminal interprets this as cancelling/interrupting an operation.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above: If you are using an xterm or similar, many terminal programs also support a "quick edit" mode, where selecting text with the mouse automatically copies it (sometimes you have to press enter), and clicking right mouse button inserts at the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard is the most assured method but if you are slightly more comfortable with mouse click functions then you can 
1) highlight the text with the mouse and RT CLICK for copy - and 
2) middle mouse button (click wheelie) for paste